# Is it better for php-fpm Unix Socket in ephemeral storage or EBS?

Tags: linux, nginx, amazon-ec2, php

I'm trying to tune my EC2 performance. One of it is to utilize the ephemeral storage for all I/O. For php-fpm, I'm utilizing unix socket instead of tcp/ip since everything is local. Considering EBS storage only has 24 IOPS (for 8GB), I'm wondering if it's better to move the php-fpm socket to ephemeral storage. Is there any I/O activity inside the unix socket file since the file size is always 0

```
[root@ php-fpm]# ls -al
total 12
drwxr-xr-x  2 root  root  4096 Aug  5 19:37 .
drwxr-xr-x 16 root  root  4096 Aug  7 03:27 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root  root     4 Aug  5 19:37 php-fpm.pid
srw-rw-rw-  1 nginx nginx    0 Aug  5 19:37 php-fpm.sock
```

Comment: a socket is just a "virtual" file to allow standard fopen/fread/fwrite operations directly to a program. a file socket should NOT produce any network i/o because it's purely a local construct, even if the filesystem is a network-mounted one.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. So I think it won't help much to move unix sockets to ephemeral storage since there is no disk I/O occurs.

Answer (score 1):

EBS is a network based service, so every single operation depends on Network. [The docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EBSVolumes.html) say:

```
An Amazon EBS volume is off-instance storage that can persist independently from the life of an instance.
```

Consider Ephemeral storage for your socket. If you use EBS, don't forget to allocate all disk with disk dupe before first use:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/xvdf bs=1M
```

But don't do it on the root / disk, just on extra EBS disk if you prefer to use that.

P.S. How to warm up EBS, please read all details in the [official docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-prewarm.html).

Comment: I don't have any extra EBS volume other than the root one. So I think I don't need to run this command. Thanks anyway.